# Upload files to Cloud Storage from iOS, authenticated by App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

We have an iOS app with App Engine and Cloud Endpoints as backend running java. We use custom user authentication so the user can log in with their own account or with Facebook. We do not use the built in user authentication in App Engine because it requires Google accounts.

We want to let users upload photos and videos from the app to Cloud Storage. In order to do this, the user must be authenticated in our App Engine backend first. What is the correct approach for combining these technologies in the given scenario?

Answer (score 1):

First I find letting the control to iOS app to directly upload files to GCS is hard behaviour,

My suggestion to this will be have an endpoint which let the iOS app to upload the file then so do any processing (if required) and upload it to the GCS, this way the API have complete control over the process where you can have authentication checks , processing , custom actions etc

Comment: Won't that occupy the entire instance for the time it's being uploaded?

Comment: if you set the threadsafe to true in appengine-web.xml then the request are parallel so it wont block the other request

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the only way to do what you said would be to have an endpoint with a String as a parameter and then you Base64 encode an object to then pass to the endpoint. However, there is a 1mb limit on the input param so your suggestion would only work for objects <1mb in size.

Answer (score 1):

To play the devil's advocate, I'll remind that it's not *necessary* to send it to your app first, only this is preferred since you can take custom actions, deal with file duplicates, take actions based on the file contents, etc...

Technically, however, you could use the [javascript API to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples) and bypass the need to send the traffic through your instance. This is particularly attractive if you're designing a web-app that uses rich client-side technology (various JS frameworks) to present a UI and manage application logic, rather than a traditional server-heavy web-app, in which case it makes sense to have the upload logic closer to the rest of your application logic, in the browser's JS.

This is also attractive if you expect high volume on your file uploads, in which case you'll want to avoid as much traffic costs as you can, freeing your instances to serve the site's dynamic resources.